# Indirect questions: Can you explain how you will or how will you?

Tags: indirect-question

Do you say:
"Can you explain me how you will do that?" or "Can you explain me how will you do that?"

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I'd say "Can you explain _to_ me how..."

Comment: It can't be "explain me" becasue 'me' is intended to be the recipient of the action of explanation and 'how you will do that" is what will be explained. The verb "explain" in this case has two objects, a direct one (what will be explained) and an indrect one (the person to whom the explanation will be given). The indrect object is indicated by being in the 'dative case' which, in  English, is constructed by placing the preposition 'to' in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Can you explain **to** me* [*how you will do that*]?
>
> [2] *Can you explain **to** me* [*how will you do that*]?

Preliminary points: there are no objects, either direct or indirect, and "me" should be replaced by the preposition phrase "to me".

The bracketed elements are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions) functioning as complement of "explain". Such clauses don't normally have subject-auxiliary inversion, so [1] is correct.

The meaning is "Can you explain to me the answer to the question 'How will you do that?'"